# mvc4 jquery .ajax success not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view with a partial view in it. I have a model in the view  and a kendogrid in the partial view. I also have an ajax call to teh controller just updates my model without returning a view. Say I need to click a toolbar button on the grid that generates an id. Now i want to return that id to the view(by updating model with that id). But success(data) is not firing

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ Id: pId, schId: sId}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            cache: false,
            url: '@(Url.Action("Process", "Controller"))',
            success: function (data) {
                var abc = data.InvoiceId;---->not fired
            },
        });
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Process(int Id, int schId, SearchModel mymodel, [DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            int myId = -1;

                // generate the Id);
        myId = generatenewId(Id,schId);-- this gets generated and myId is updated
            }

            mymodel.Id = myId 
            return View(mymodel)

        }
```

Comment: You specify that you expect JSON in the response with dataType: "JSON", but you send "View(model)" result in your action. This could surely cause some misbehaviour. You should probably use simply "return Json(mymodel)" in you action as a result.

Comment: Are you hitting your Controller's Action if/when you debug?

Comment: If you use Kendo Grid, using `$("#your-grid").kendoGrid({ dataSource:  { type: "json", ... })` could be a lot easier.

Comment: If the success isn't fired, the error is. Try adding an error callback and inspecting the three parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it using a mail form!

Look at the signature in my controller I use **JsonResult** not **ActionResult**!
Also I return JSON not a View!

```
return Json(result);
```

**IN MY CONTROLLER**

```
 public JsonResult AjaxMailer(MailerModel model)
 {
            Emailer mailer = new Emailer();
            JsonResult Jr = new JsonResult();
            string result = mailer.DispatchEmail(model.phone, model.name, model.message, model.email);
            return Json(result);
 }
```

**JAVASCRIPT IN MY VIEW**

```
function imClicked(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var messageObj = 
   {
       "name": "",
       "email": "",
       "phone": "",
       "message": "",

   };
    messageObj.name = $("#name").val();
    messageObj.email = $("#email").val();
    messageObj.phone = $("#phone").val();
    messageObj.message = $("#message").val();

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Contact/AjaxMailer',
        data: JSON.stringify(messageObj),
        error: printError,
        success: mailsent

    });
};
```

Comment: He should not use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet unless he needs to. The OP has set the request method to "POST", so no need for that.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási opps I missed that updated per request!

Answer (score 0):

You should decide wether you want to send a HTML result (view), or JSON result (Json), and call the corresponding result in your Action. If you set the `dataType` to JSON in your jQuery Ajax call, you should return Json result, for example:

```
public ActionResult Process(int Id, int schId, SearchModel mymodel, [DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
  int myId = -1;
  // generate the Id);
  myId = generatenewId(Id,schId);-- this gets generated and myId is updated
  mymodel.Id = myId 
  return Json(mymodel) // this will return Json in the response containing your model object
  //return View(mymodel) !!! This would return a full HTML response rendered with you model
}
```